# How do I match from the last occurring set of characters in an OR statement?

Tags: regex

I have this string I want to test again:

```
<<Hello>>
<<I am Going->To>>

expected matches:
Hello
To
```

and I'm using this pattern:

```regex
(?<=->|<<)(?:.+)(?=\>{2}|->)
```

What I want is that it matches a string after `->` and ending before `>>`. Unless the `->` doesn't exist, then I want to match it with `<<` instead.

But the `or` statement I have written - `(?<=->|<<)` - starts matching `<<` immediately. I hoped it would look in order through the entire string but unfortunately it looks at both alternatives at the same time, which does make more sense.

How would I approach this?

Comment: Why to tag `c#`?

Comment: yeah sorry, stackoverflow suggested a language tag so I just followed it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: You may also use `Regex.Match(s, @".*(?:->|<<)(.+)[>-]>").Groups[1].Value`

Comment: Check [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55398846/3832970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?!.*->)(?<=->|<<)(?:.+)(?=>>)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RLHnF1/1)

Answer (score 1):

You might use:

```
(?<=<<)(?:(?!->).)+(?=>>)|(?<=->).*?(?=>>)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%3c%3c%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f!-%3e%29.%29%2b%28%3f%3d%3e%3e%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3d-%3e%29.*%3f%28%3f%3d%3e%3e%29&i=%3c%3cHello%3e%3e%0d%0a%3c%3cI+am+Going-%3eTo%3e%3e)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=<<)` Positive lookbehind, assert that is directly on the left is
- `(?:(?!->).)+` Match any char if what follows is not ->
- `(?=>>)` Assert what is directly on the right is >>
- `|` Or
- `(?<=->)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly on the left is
- `.*?` Match any char non greedy
- `(?=>>)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is >>

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
.*(?:->|<<)(.+)[>-]>
```

and get Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%28%3F%3A-%3E%7C%3C%3C%29%28.%2B%29%5B%3E-%5D%3E&i=%3C%3CHello%3E%3E%0D%0A%3C%3CI%20am%20Going-%3ETo%3E%3E).

**Details**

- `.*` - match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?:->|<<)` - match either `->` or `<<`
- `(.+)` - from the current location, capture into Group 1 any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `[>-]>` - match `>` or `-` followed with `>`.

[image]

C#:

```
var result = Regex.Match(s, @".*(?:->|<<)(.+)[>-]>")?.Groups[1].Value;
```